# How can I bind a button rendered by a React component to a function in that component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called Quote that renders randomly generated quotes. By the nature of them being randomly generated, it has a method that updates their state:

```
async update() {
        let response = await fetchQuote();
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            quoteAuthor: response.author,
            quote: response.quote
        });
    }
```

and is rendered as:

```
render() {
        return (
                <div className="main">
                    <h1>{this.state.quoteAuthor}</h1>
                    <p>{this.state.quote}</p>
                    <button onClick={this.update}>New quote</button>
                </div>
        );
    }
```

I want the button the generated a new quote but when clicked I get `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this is undefined`. If I modify it so it to `onClick={this.update()}` it rapidly updates as fast as it can without stopping, regardless if I click the button.

Here's the entire class:

```
/* component for the quote */
export default class Quote extends React.Component {
    /* placeholder */
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            quoteAuthor: "Rick Osborne", 
            quote: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live."
        }
    }
    /* actually render things */
    render() {
        return (
                <div className="main">
                    <h1>{this.state.quoteAuthor}</h1>
                    <p>{this.state.quote}</p>
                    <button onClick={this.update}>New quote</button>
                </div>
        );
    }

    /* async fetch the quotes and reassign the variables to them once processed */
    async update() {
        let response = await fetchQuote();
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            quoteAuthor: response.author,
            quote: response.quote
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `update` function to arrow function so that it will be pointing context `this`,

```
  update = async() => {
    let response = await fetchQuote();
    console.log(response);
    this.setState({
      quoteAuthor: response.quoteAuthor,
      quote: response.quote
    });
  };
```

> [**Working example here..**](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-change-state-xynvq)

In `setState` , You can assign the values from response you receive from api.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the click handler in the component's constructor. You can also have a look at React's guide on [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        quoteAuthor: "Rick Osborne", 
        quote: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live."
    }

    this.update = this.update.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the function like this.

`Two ways to bind the function`

- Constructor Mode

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    ...
  };

  this.update = this.update.bind(this);
}
```

- Arrow function Mode

```
const update = async () => {
  ...
}
```